# How to handle large taxonomy

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Have a page on website where exposed filter is hierarchical taxonomy (Country/City). Works fine with few terms, just for test. Page loadtime is 1.5ms, choosing terms goes in blink.

Now i imported all Europe countries and cities, around 5000 terms. Page loadtime is 21s.
Choosing first term (parent/UK) took 8 seconds. Choosing 2nd term (child/London) took 8 seconds.
I am using views exposed filter http://drupal.org/sandbox/ser_house/1832320.

I am aware that this module is far from done but from what i found out reading about taxonomy is that Drupal handles large taxonomies very bad.

All countries and cities will be around 20.000-30.000 terms and i except several users using the filter at same time which is not an option with loadspeed so high.

Any help how to handle this (maybe another module?) would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

If still relevant, you can try out [Taxonomy Edge](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_edge).

It has optimizations for taxonomies in general, and also implements views filter/arguments for taxonomies.